# why do the file permission keep changing?

Tags: php, linux, apache, file-permissions, syslog-ng

I am using a rapsberry pi as a poor man's syslog server using sylog-ng. I wanted to create a simple web page where our NOC could easily view the log file, so I am also running Apache. I have syslog-ng writing any syslog messages it receives to a file that is in the same directory of the index.php file of the web page. I am then using php to output the contents of the log file. This is where I am running into problems. If I run the command

```
    chmod 755 /var/www/html/syslog.txt
```

the web page works just fine, but as soon as syslog-ng updates the log file the permissions revert, and php is no longer able to open the file. Here is what the permissions keep reverting back to:

```
    -rw-r----- 1 root adm 11977 Mar 22 13:58 syslog.txt
```

I have even tried changing the user to root, but it keep reverting back to adm as well.

Comment: https://syslog-ng.com/wiki/syslog-ng-faq-permission

Comment: FWIW: On something like a Pi, you're likely better off using a lighter server like nginx or lighttpd.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! SO is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux and its applications. SuperUser.com or unix.stackexchange.com would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/), [Internet of Things Stack Exchange](http://iot.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking every time the file is written to the permissions are changed back. As Alex Howansky has linked to a setting that may allow you to change this.

It could also be possible to read and echo the file from its original location using php in your index.php like this:

```
<?php
$myFile = "/var/log/syslog.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');
$theData = fread($fh, 1);
fclose($fh);
echo $theData;
?>
```

Add www-data to the adm group.